# How exactly Matlab performs the Lasso classification?

Tags: matlab, lambda, cross-validation, lasso-regression

I am doing some research on Lasso classification method. I have a 40x15 dataset and I want to develop a binomial equation without dividing data into train and test set (because of small sample size).

I need some specific details on how exactly Matlab performs the LASSO (*lassoglm*). I know the general concept of how it works regarding removing insignificant terms by applying a penalty term to the coefficients, I also know about the *CV* and how it takes a subset of data and perform the analysis on that subset, but I still have some specific question about the process of LASSO in Matlab.

I want to know:

- in the case of not using *CV*, and just doing the *B=lassoglm(X,Y)*, what are the values of *B*? Is it the matrix of *X* coefficients that I can use for the binomial equation?
- can I still be able to extract *Index1SE* and *IndexMinDeviance* to have the most significant terms contributing to my model without using *CV*?
- as *CV* finds the optimal value for lambda, when I, for example, use *CV=10* how does the Matlab perform the lasso (*lambda=100*)? Does Matlab perform different analysis for each value of lambda? If so, *HOW*? and *HOW* it plots the *Lambda-Deviance* graph, having **different error bars**?
- and finally, can I just ignore *CV* and do simple Lassoglm classification, but still find the best, significant terms out of my 15 terms and then form a binomial formulation (having Intercept,C, and X coefficients)

Comment: It sounds like something that you should ask TMW. Either way, I believe this is off-topic for SO, but possibly on-topic for [stats.se] (voted to migrate), or even [scicomp.se]. BTW, if you open `lassoglm.m` you can see how it works. It has some nice in-code documentation.